# Determine folder Size

Tags: objective-c, macos, filesize

With this code I determine the file size if the checkbox is NSOnState, but with a folder value is always 0. The directory is correct.
Can you help me?

```
unsigned long long resultsize=0;
if(imagehistoryS.state == NSOnState) {
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Users/Giovanni/Desktop/test", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]];     
    NSNumber *fileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil] objectForKey:NSFileSize];
    resultsize += [fileSize doubleValue];
}
[result setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total size items selected: %f", resultsize]];
```

Comment: Why are you adding a double to an unsigned long long?

Comment: I'm beginner. Without doubleValue in [fileSize doubleValue]; the code don't work. What can I write?

Comment: Well, as you are adding it to an `unsigned long long`, you should use `fileSize unsignedLongLongValue];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in a string, and yet specifying the `NSUserDomainMask`. I've tried this and it works.

```
NSUInteger resultSize = 0;

NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

NSURL *LibraryURL = [[fm URLsForDirectory:NSLibraryDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSURL *previewsURL = [LibraryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Webpage Previews"];

resultSize = [[[fm attributesOfItemAtPath:[previewsURL path] error:nil] objectForKey:NSFileSize] unsignedIntegerValue];

NSLog(@"Size: %lu", resultSize);
```

This is for an ARC environment.

Note, I'm using NSURLs instead of NSString filepaths as much as possible. Also, you don't need to hardcode the user's name in the search path.

**Updated to show the specific folder as requested in the comments**

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm beginner. NSUserDomainMask is the problem? How can I modify my code with your suggestions with this directory "%@/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Webpage Previews"?

Comment: @Joannes - I've updated my answer. The idea is to get the system folder, then drill down as you want.

Comment: The code works, but the size is wrong. This folder "/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Webpage Previews" is 23Mb but in NSLog display 3.1Kb. The same problem with my code, size wrong. I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: This does not give the size of the directory including all files within.

Comment: Anyway to get the size of the directory including all its files?

Answer (score 0):

In you `stringWithFormat` you are missing the format specifier `%@`.